# Content in header moving when i scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

**I need to make the sticky header in css.**

But I got a problem. When I scroll through the google chrome browser page the content in the sticky section jerks. This is annoying. Moves literally 1 pixel but catches the eye.

I have the same task as in this example which I found on stack overflow. You may not notice this bug right away.

But this is clearly visible if you zoom in on the element or look at a monitor with a low expansion. The elements are literally jumping around. I want the elements not to move when the page is scrolled.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  position:relative;
}

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100");

h1 {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.header:nth-of-type(1){
   background-color: dodgerblue;

}

.header:nth-of-type(2){
   background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.header:nth-of-type(3){
   background-color: chartreuse;
}

.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(70deg, orange, crimson);
  padding-top: 50px;
    
}

.header-2{
  top: 50px;
}

.header-3{
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section>
<header class="header"><h1>HEADER 1</h1></header>
<div class="content"><h1>CONTENT</h1></div>
<header class="header header-2"><h1>HEADER 2</h1></header>
<div class="content"><h1>CONTENT</h1></div>
<header class="header header-3"><h1>HEADER 3</h1></header>
<div class="content"><h1>CONTENT</h1></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Cant reproduce, neither in Chromium nor in Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04LTS. Have you tried a other browser?

Comment: Yes. I tried Safari and everything works well

Comment: I think there is not much you can do. But i would like to be taught a better one. So im waiting with you here ;)